# Groovy - how to define and use links and send it in mail

Tags: groovy

I tried to define a link and send it in mail. Everything I tried I didn't get expected results. Could someone help me? Here is what I tried:

```
def location = "http://www.google.com"
mail_message = "${location}\n\n" - works but full location isa writing
 try1         = "<a href=\'${location}\'>name1</a>"
  mail_message += "<${try1}>" + " \n\n" - get garbage

  String try2 =  "<a href='${report_location}' target='_blank'>" +  "name2" + "</a>";
  mail_message += "${try2}" + "\n\n" - get garbage
```

both look almost the same in mail body:

```
<<a href='https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&amp;data=04%7C01%7Cdolevk%40hailo.ai%7Cc062c2e56cd647d1f7b308d8c8df0f3b%7C6ae4a5f7546741898f6af2928ed536de%7C0%7C0%7C637480207647114779%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&amp;sdata=zlXx3lp%2Bl2bPgeCw7RU2Gim1Jh5MZqzxVUEeli%2FG85g%3D&amp;reserved=0'>name1</a>> 

<a href='https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&amp;data=04%7C01%7Cdolevk%40hailo.ai%7Cc062c2e56cd647d1f7b308d8c8df0f3b%7C6ae4a5f7546741898f6af2928ed536de%7C0%7C0%7C637480207647114779%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&amp;sdata=zlXx3lp%2Bl2bPgeCw7RU2Gim1Jh5MZqzxVUEeli%2FG85g%3D&amp;reserved=0' target='_blank'>name2</a>
```

Comment: If you just send plain text emails, Outlook will recognize automatically a link like `http://www.example.com` displaying it correctly and making it clickable.
However, it looks like your Outlook server modifies your links to avoid clicking dangerous links.

Comment: That's right but if I want to use hyper link called name1 that point to www.google.com. how to defined this hyperlink in groovy.

Comment: What's wrong with this one:
`def location = "http://www.google.com";
def name = 'name';
def link =  "<a href='$location' target='_blank'>$name</a>"`

Comment: Hi,                                                                                                                                
def location = "http://www.google.com"; def name = 'name'; def link =  "<a href='$location' target='_blank'>$name</a>";message += "${link}"                                                                                             I tried to use this code but still get garbage,                                                          
BTW if I use this code message += "http://www.google.com";                                             the link work perfect

Comment: here is the output:  <a href='https://eur02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&amp;data=04%7C01%7Cdolevk%40hailo.ai%7C9fde30dde19749687eed08d8cb4d23cd%7C6ae4a5f7546741898f6af2928ed536de%7C0%7C0%7C637482879470456533%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&amp;sdata=fYXBMCq4tbuSWyaKwJCdzWcXU0nliZvhALP6pi7iGao%3D&amp;reserved=0' target='_blank'>name</a>

Comment: Hi again, thanks a lot for the support ,maybe the problem is the way I sending the mail: emailext body: "${mail_message}",to: "mail address" @Catalin

Comment: Your code works fine, the problem is not there, where you build the message body, but somewhere else.